# Rails Server Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am following a tutorial to create a class project.

I can generate a new rails project with

```
   $ rails project
```

The problem Im having is when I try to start my server, It will generate a project called server:

```
   $ rails server
```

or

```
   $ rails s
```

I figured out that I need to install/update rails to 3.0.3 to use this command every time I open terminal. I find myself having to install gems(bundle, etc) every time I need to work on my project.

Is there anyway to save this terminal session or profile for later use?

Is it user error?

Im new to Rails and about the same with terminal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have resorted to leaving my computer and terminal open for about a week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on board! - You'll have fun, I found setting up the environment the most difficult thing.
in rails 2 you start the server with `ruby script/server`.

to upgrade to rails 3 try `gem install rails -v=3.0.4`
I put the version but it's not a mandatory option.
To uninstall a gem (as rails is) is `gem uninstall gemname -v=x.x.x`. - 
`gem list` will tell you the version of each gem.
I hope you've got rvm, if not I strongly sugget you to install it, this will allow you not only to use different versions of ruby but also to set different gemsets, therefor one each project, you'll find it useful.

Once in rails 3 you can use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/),  have a look at [this episode of railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler), by the way this is a very good site, but you may know it already.

**another edit...**
I don't know the behavior you're describing, looks like something is wrong with your environment, but I need to know if you have rvm to solve this, if so try `rvm list` and `rvm gemset`, With the first you get the list of installed ruby, you can switch between them with `rvm 1.9.2` i.e. and `rvm 1.9.2@gemdirname` with the gemdir coming from the second list. You should find your configuration in one of those list.

Comment: I am using RVM with with my rails install. i figured out my problem with your first comment. It hit me out of know where. It was making a new project with ` $ rails s ` because I skipped this step in my RVM POST install.` [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.` So every time I closed my terminal window it killed the session where I bundled the RVM install and I had to do this every time. Once I added this to my .bash_profile everything works fine. thank you guys for quick reply!! @supriya, @Mahesh

Comment: You right! I didn't think about that but it makes perfectly sense! - good to know you're back on track

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using rails 2.8 or lesser use this to start the server

```
ruby script/server
```

Answer (score 0):

`rails new project` is for new rails project n `rails s` is for starting server